# express-ws: add prototype via typescript

Tags: typescript, prototype, express-ws

I'm using `express-ws` for WebSockets. 
I want to extend the `WebSocket` class in the `ws` module that `express-ws` import and add it a string as prototype. (`WebSocket.prototype.str: string = ""`). 
i should mention that I'm using typescript. 
Who can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may work. Just makesure that `WebSocket` is an interface

```
import {WebSockets} from './express-ws';

interface WebSocket {
    str:string;
}


// Type definition for the spy function 
declare module './express-ws' {
    namespace WebSockets {
        export interface WebSocket {
            str: string;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I know what's the problem.
`WebSocket` in `ws` module is not an interface. It's the main class.
Is there a way to do that now?